# Youtube скачивание видео Python с обрезанием по времени

Tags: python

Никто не посоветует, чем можно скачать видео, обрезав по времени?

Сейчас я получаю ссылку на видео с помощью PyTube

```
url = pytube.YouTube(url_video).streams.get
```

А качаю и обрезаю с помощью ffmpeg

```
try:
                process_call_str = 'ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -ss {1} -to {2} -i "{0}" -acodec aac -b:a 192k -avoid_negative_ts make_zero "{3}"'.format(
                    str(url), str("00:00:00"), str("00:06:00"), "videos/" + video_id + ".mp4")
                status = subprocess.check_call(process_call_str, shell=True)
                print("Видео", url_video, "загружено")
                break
            except:
                continue
```

К сожалению ffmpeg грузить процессор под 100%, нету более простого способа?

Comment: Но ведь вы зачем-то его перекодируете, а не просто скачиваете. Уберите перекодирование, и он не будет ничего грузить

Comment: @andreymal а не подскажете, что именно удалить, а то я с ffmpeg не работал, а код нашел в интернете

Comment: Что-то вроде `-vcodec copy -acodec copy`

Comment: @andreymal спасибо